# MockMvc show corresponding curl command or http request

Tags: java, api, spring-mvc, curl

I have a line of code that performs a request to an API but I can't figure out the exact format of the request. 
`mapper.writeValueAsString` from [here](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.8/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString%28java.lang.Object%29).

`mockMvc` from [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/setup/MockMvcBuilders.html).

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/press/group").param("filterId", filterId).content(mapper.writeValueAsString(someObject)).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
```

I'm trying to convert the code to Python and if there's a way to have my `mockMvc` output the corresponding HTML request it would be very helpful. The API I'm querying lacks documentation

Thanks and any guidance is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

MockMvc allows you to print both the request and the response.
In your case, you should do:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/press/group").param("filterId", filterId).content(mapper.writeValueAsString(someObject)).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andDo(print());
```

This will print the output to the console, and it will look something like this:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = POST
         Request URI = /press/group
          Parameters = {filterId=[filterId_val]}
             Headers = {}
             Handler:
                Type = com.yourCompany.yourController
              Method = public ReturnType com.yourCompany.yourController.yourHandlerMethod(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.String)
               Async:
       Async started = false
        Async result = null
Resolved Exception:
                Type = null
        ModelAndView:
           View name = null
                View = null
               Model = null
            FlashMap:
MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 200
       Error message = null
             Headers = {}
        Content type = null
                Body = {"val1" : "val_one"}
       Forwarded URL = null
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

This should be enough info for you to construct the http request in python.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about mockMVC, but if this gets rendered in an HTML page, you could use the Chrome developer tools to generate the curl statement for you.

Start Tools/Developer Tools, click the network tab, click the link/button/thing that causes the request, find the request in the Network tab, right click, copy as cUrl.

Obviously, if it's not rendered in an HTML page, this isn't going to be a great deal of help.

Answer (score 0):

Extract value of string of `mapper.writeValueAsString(someObject)`

this string is JSON `(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` so it should look like:

```
{"attribute":"value","attribute":"value"}
```

And `param("filterId", filterId)`
is added to your url (variable `filterId` is some string so extract it)

```
/press/group?filterId:filterIdString
```

Paste it to the curl message:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"attribute":"value","attribute":"value"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" "admin:password@localhost:8080/press/group?filterId:filterId" -i
```

Look at response

Explanation

`X` type of request

`-d` data

`-H` content type

`admin:passwor@` credentials

`-i` informations